# Error: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, boolean, angular2-observables

I am working on a following code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private router: Router) {
  }


  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable <boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

      
    return this.afAuth.authState
      .pipe(
        map(user => user !== null),
        tap(value => {
          if (!value) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login').then();
            return value;
          } else {
            return value;
          }
        })
      );
  }

}
```

Versions i have are:

Angular CLI: 13.1.4

Node: 16.14.0

I have this error in this part of code:

```
 return this.afAuth.authState
      .pipe(
        map(user => user !== null),
        tap(value => {
          if (!value) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login').then();
            return value;
          } else {
            return value;
          }
        })
```

Saying:

> Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>'.Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean | UrlTree>'.Types of property 'source' are incompatible.

Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: 2 issues. The map should be a filter, and the tap should be a map. The returns in the tap won’t work hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap), the tap operator is "A function that returns an Observable identical to the source, but runs the specified Observer or callback(s) for each item".

Which means you don't have to `return value` in a tap. It will be done by default.

In the other hand, you don't want to redirect the route after returning the boolean value, you need to do it before.

So i suggest you to change your code into this :

```
    return this.afAuth.authState
              .pipe(
                map(user => { 
                   const isLogged = !!user;
                   if(!isLogged){
                      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login')
                      return false;
                   } else {
                      return true
                   }
                })
);
```

Also it might happen that on a page refresh (F5), the `this.afAuth.authState` emits first a `null` value right before the `user` object.
That would gives you a rejection whereas the user is logged.
In that case I suggest you to add a [debounceTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime) operator before the map.

Answer (score 0):

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable<boolean | UrlTree>

your return type is of observable while in the method signature you defined return type to be  Observable <boolean | UrlTree>

a possible solution is to check what `this.afAuth.authState` return and update it's signature to return `Observable<boolean | UrlTree>`